# ExtJS 5.1 Remember Me on local store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to do Remember Me with an interesting algorithm. I was thinking, when i click the Remember Me and Login, the value of the text fields (username&password) will be saved as a default value. My login button click event here:

```
    var username = Ext.getCmp('setNo').getValue();
    var password= Ext.getCmp('setPass').getValue();

    if(refs.checkStudent.value === true){
        Ext.getCmp('setNo').setValue(username);
        Ext.getCmp('setPass').setValue(password);
    }
    else{
        Ext.getCmp('setNo').setValue("");
        Ext.getCmp('setParola').setValue("");
    }
```

**On console, it is working. But I'm working with a local store, no server. So when i refresh the page, it's gone. Is there a way to not lose them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your view `onAfterRender` event:

```
Ext.getCmp('setNo').setValue(localStorage.username);
Ext.getCmp('setPass').setValue(localStorage.password);
```

on your button click event:

```
if (refs.checkStudent.value === true) {
    localStorage.username = Ext.getCmp('setNo').getValue();
    localStorage.password = Ext.getCmp('setPass').getValue();
} else {
    localStorage.removeItem('username');
    localStorage.removeItem('password');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use ExtJs utility to set and get values in cookies. At time of login set 
username and password in cookies and after refresh the page read username
and password value from the cookie. 

Ext.util.Cookies.set('username', username); // To set value in cookie.
Ext.util.Cookies.get('username'); // to get value form cookie.
```

Comment: You could also use local storage to do it.